# Remove characters only from starting in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

I am taking data from two input Excel files and processing them with the help of pandas dataframe. Excel has large data and number of columns. However I have created simple examples to illustrate this question

Following is first dataframe df_s1(action needs to perform on Part Number Column)-
[image: first input dataframe]

Following is second dataframe df_s2(here some special charaters are mentioned and I have to remove these characters only from starting of df_s1['Part Number'], These characters are very large including *, 2*, ((*2) etc... I have mentioned limited)-
[image: Second datframe]

I want following output after processing df_s1 with the help of df_s2-
[image: Output dataframe]

Now problem statement is I have to delete(remove) all the special characters only from starting of column **Part Number** in df_s1(first dataframe). Information about these special characters are mentioned in df_s2(second dataframe **Special Character** Column(large number of characters including(,*...)

I have tried following code to achieve it. Also I have prepared sample dataframes in my code so that it will be easy for solution)

```
#first dataframe and remove special charaters from starting of part number column

import pandas as pd
df_s1 = pd.DataFrame({'Part Number' : ['(2)CAB-ETHS-RJ45',' 2*VEDGE-CAB-C13-XXX','(4X)CAB-ETHXOVER','1*VEDGE-ABCD','2*73ETHER-387','4xCBTA-98CD','5xNBOC','(1)289RG7','2 CDXG59','(7x)29FG2ZT-AB','((*2)FGDT-X78','((4))RGD-RX78','EDXC-Y82','D92ZT-3A','FTZT-9A7'], 
                    'ID' : ['1','2','3','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','5','4','4','6']
                  })
#Following special charaters needs to remove from starting of part number column of first dataframe
df_s2 = pd.DataFrame({'Special Charater':['(2)','2*','(4X)','1*','4x','5x','(1)','2 ','(7x)','((*2)','((4))']})
for i in df_s2['Special Charater']:
    j=0
    for k in df_s1['Part Number']:
        if str(k).startswith(str(i)):
            df_s1['Part Number'][j] = str(k[len(i):])

        
        else:
            j+=1

df_s1
```

However I am getting following required output from above code except 1 part number `2*VEDGE-CAB-C13-XXX` in which 2* is not removed

[image: output of my code]

I am looking for-

1. I know it is not standard way to achieve this task through pandas. So could you please help me with your pandas python solution for it like `df.str.findall().str.replace()`. I am unable to put this type of standard approach in my solution. Just we have to replace all characters mentioned as it is in second dataframe from starting of first dataframe part number column
2. I am not able to figure out the reason why `2*VEDGE-CAB-C13-XXX` 2* is not removed from starting in my solution while other special character removes from starting

Hope I am clear and very positive to get another approach of this problem

Answer (score 0):

**1ts attemp**

You can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) from pandas. This applies a regular expression on the string and returns a column for each group. Because you want to total match, you need only the first group in colmn `0`.

```
df['Part Number'].str.extract('(([A-Z\d]+)+(-.*)?)$', expand=False)[0]
```

What does `(([A-Z\d]+)(-.*)?)$` do?

- `$` is the end of the string, so we only want groups at the end
- `(-.*)?` is a group, which matches all letters after `-`. This group can be found zero or more times, represented by `?`
- `([A-Z\d]+)` is a group which matches at least one capital letter or digit.

The combination of this two groups is the string you want to extrapolate.

**2nd attemp**

You could define a regular expression and use the pandas [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.Series.str.replace) option.
As far as I see, you want to repalce all elements before an asterix `*`, an empty space   an `x` or a closing bracket `)`. The code below trys to find 1 match at most, beginning on the left side of the string.

```
df_s1['Part Number'].str.replace('(.*[x| |\)|\*])', '', n=1)
```

**3rd attempt**

You could try the code below, because you know all the strings you want to replace. In this case, you loop over each string multiple times, and if you find an unwanted substring you substitute the string with an empty one.

```
def replace(x):
    for item in ['(2)','2*','(4X)','1*','4x','5x','(1)','2 ','(7x)','((*2)','((4))']:
        x = x.replace(item, '')
    return x

df_s1['Part Number'].apply(replace)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there are two points here to note. I have to replace only from starting of the string present in every cell. Second point in special character column has hundreds of rows which is hard to bind in a code with static values. Is there any way as described in my approach

Comment: again thank you very much for your answer. Still  2*VEDGE-CAB-C13-XXX 
 for this part number updated solution gives empty value

Comment: I don't get an empty string for `2*VEDGE-CAB-C13-XXX`. You can try my regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/) and see that the matches are correct.

Comment: thanks. I have checked in above link and regex is giving full match for this particular case 2*VEDGE-CAB-C13-XXX. It is removing and I think this may be the reason. Could you please check

Comment: What is the regex you use? Both of my suggestions do work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this code for an alternate solution:

```
import re

for sp_char in df_s2['Special Character']:
    df_s1['Part Number'] = df_s1['Part Number'].replace({'^'+re.escape(sp_char): ""}, regex=True)

print(df_s1)
```

The `re.escape()` is specifically used to add backslashes to all special characters (which might be the reason why some solutions you tried are not working)

---

On some further work, I was able to use the dictionary option to make the code much more optimised. The earlier method with the for-loop takes about **25-80ms**, and the dictionary method runs in around **3-20ms**. The updated methodology will take more memory and should be kept in mind if the database is quite a lot larger.

Do note, I have also added `^` that will make the regex expression to match characters from the starting of the string only.

```
import re

replace_dict = {'^'+re.escape(sp_char): '' for sp_char in df_s2['Special Character']}
df_s1['Part Number'] = df_s1['Part Number'].replace(replace_dict, regex=True)
```

Comment: thank you very much for giving this solution and your precious time. It will be good if there is more optimised way to achieve specified task. I want to mention one thing is that we need to remove these characters from starting only. However replace will work on full string rather from starting only. Hope I am clear regarding this point. Thanks

Comment: @VishavGupta I have added a more optimised code to achieve the solution. I am still working on a (simple) solution for removing the characters from the starting only and will try and update the post with that soon.

Comment: Updated solution again so that it now only works if characters are at the starting of the string

Comment: noted. Thank you very much for this solution